# Hiding all children based on world position in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 50 items in unity that are children of the same parent. I want to hide them when their world X location exceeds a set number. I have a script that a friend provided but I don't understand why it doesn't work. The effects are shown in the video below.

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

private MeshRenderer[] renderers;

void Awake()
{

    renderers = new MeshRenderer[transform.childCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        renderers[i] = transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
}
void Update()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        renderers[i].enabled = transform.GetChild(i).position.x < 0;
}
```

[Example of current Behaviour](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tf30awii53tqx0z/Hide_Problem.mp4?dl=0)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There isn't anything obviously wrong with your code. The code enables the renderers of all children that have a negative world position on the x axis and disables the others. In your video it isn't very easy to track the positions of these objects. Maybe when debugging your setup you could make use of Debug.Log.

Comment: I found the cause of the confusion, there was another script instantiating the same object in the same location. And it should be > 0 too. Will leave the post here in case someone wants to re use it.

Comment: just a sidenote: You could simply use a `renderers = GetComponentInChildren<MeshRenderer>()`. And why agin use `transform.GetChild`? you could simply use `renderers[i].enabled = renderers[i].transform.position.x < 0;` since every component also stores a reference to according `Transform` it is attached to. This way you can be sure you are always checking the correct position and it's also more efficient.

Comment: Btw as I can see in your video .... it actually works! The Meshrenderer component of the sphere you selected gets enabled and disabled as expected depending on the `x` position ... Is it possible that something else is wrong? Does the shader work correctly?